# Does jade's syntax support a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I tried this in jade served by express but got "unexpected identifier" as an error.

```
- switch(myvar)
    - case: "0"
        span First Case
            break
    - case: "2"
        span Second Case
            break
    - case: "3"
        span Third Case
            break
    - case: "4"
        span Fourth Case
            break
```

I was curious as to what is the syntax for a switch statement, if there is one.

Update: Jade, not express.

Comment: Did you mean *"Does **node.js** have a switch statement"*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT**

This question is apparently about Jade instead.

But the answer is still yes :).

But it's called `case`:

From [the docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a6-8)

```
case friends
    when 0
        p you have no friends
    when 1 
        p you have a friend
    default
        p you have #{friends} friends
```

---

Javascript has a switch statement.

```
switch(variable){
    case 1:
        // do something
        break;
    case 2:
        // do something else
        break;
    // and so forth
    default: 
        // do something if nothing
        break;
 }
```

Being that Express.js runs in Node.js which is just JavaScript -- yes.  Express has a `switch` statement since JavaScript has a `switch` statement.  (Even coffeescript has a `switch` that "compiles" down to a JavaScript `switch` statement.)

[MDN reference: `switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

It looks like your syntax is messed up there -- what are those "-" characters?  You're also missing the `:` from the end of each `case` statement, and you're not `break`ing after each case which means the code for ALL cases will ALWAYS run regardless of the condition.

Comment: Interesting he just called it "case"

Comment: a problem i see with this is that if you put this case with the default Nothing or null inside a table will generate a whitespace, is some way to fix that?